# Isometric paper and drawing on it -- with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

I would like to create a drawing on isometric drawing paper like the following:

[image: isometric-paper]

**N.B.** Forget the drawing on top of the paper; it is just something I found in order to illustrate the type of paper I would like to have.

On the blank isometric paper, I would like to draw the following simple sketch of a house:

[image: house]

**Update**

Thanks to [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114284/15874), I created the following (which is the house from another angle):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
 \psset{linejoin = 2}
 \SpecialCoor
  \begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-2.3)(10,8.5)
    \pstVerb{gsave [0.8660254 0.5 0 1 0 -400] concat}
   {\psset{linewidth = 0.3pt, linecolor = black!50}
     \multido{\iA = 0+1}{25}{%
       \psline(\iA,-4)(\iA,20)
       \psline(!-5 \iA\space 10 sub)(!20 \iA\space 10 sub)
       \rput(!0 \iA\space 15 sub){\psline(0,0)(!\iA\space abs dup add dup)}
     }
   }
   \psset{linewidth = 2pt}
    \pspolygon(8,2)(8,6)(11,9)(11,5)
    \pspolygon(1,2)(1,6)(8,6)(8,2)
    \pspolygon(1,6)(2.5,9.5)(9.5,9.5)(8,6)
    \psline(11,9)(9.5,9.5)
   \psset{linestyle = dashed}
    \pspolygon(4,5)(4,9)(11,9)(11,5)
    \pspolygon(1,6)(4,9)(4,5)(1,2)
    \psline(4,9)(2.5,9.5)
    \pstVerb{grestore}
  \end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: house]

Comment: One can easily draw 3D objects in [`pstricks`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks) using [`pst-solides3d`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-solides3d). However, using isometric paper like the above would not work with true 3D objects, since the projection would not coincide with the 2D guidelines. So, either fake 3D (naturally, 2D) on isometric paper, or true 3D. That's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @Werner I think a fake 3D is what I'm after, but I don't know how to draw the actual isometri paper. `:(` The house itself should no be too difficult (I think).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: in your edit the roof is not symmetrical, it is 1 to 2 and not 1.5 on each side

Comment: @Herbert Good point; thank you. Is it correct after the edit?

Comment: yes, it is ok now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\psset{coorType=1,Alpha=30}% type 1 for orhtogonal x-z-axes
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(3,3)
\pstThreeDCoor[IIIDticks,zMax=6,yMax=1]
\pstThreeDLine(0,0,0)(3,0,0)(3,0,4)(0,0,4)(0,0,0)
\pstThreeDLine(3,0,4)(1.5,0,6)(0,0,4)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

the isometric lines are simple lines in the plane. However, you can use the transformation matrix and set the values so that all lines in a 2d coordinate system are isometric.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-2)(11,10)
\pstVerb{ gsave [1 0.5 0 1 0 -400] concat }
{\psset{linewidth=0.3pt,linecolor=black!30}
\multido{\iA=-0+1,\iB=-10+1,\iC=-15+1}{25}{
  \psline(\iA,-4)(\iA,20)
  \psline(-5,\iB)(20,\iB)
  \rput(0,\iC){\psline(0,0)(!\iA\space abs dup add dup )}}}
\psset{linewidth=2pt}
\pspolygon(0,0)(0,4)(3,4)(3,0)
\psline(0,4)(1.5,6)(3,4)
\psline(3,0)(10,7)(10,11)(3,4)% see isometric grid for the coordinates
\psline(1.5,6)(8.5,13)(10,11)
\pstVerb{grestore }
\end{pspicture*}
\caption{foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look into a PostScript documentation for the meaning of the transformation matrix. It is the same as the one in PDF.

Comment: This is nice, Herbert. However, I would like to have the isometric paper, i.e., the 2D triangles, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two questions: (1) Can I somehow use `pdflatex` if loading `auto-pst-pdf`? (As it is now, the lines are placed wrong if I do this.) (2) The house is not 4 units high, but something like 3½ units; how do I correct this?

Comment: I know, it is only a way how it could be done. The distance outside of the matrix is the default unit, you can correct it. I have no idea why pdflatex fails.

Comment: Okay about `pdflatex`; I will just use `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` instead. I don't quite understand how to change the units to corret the problem. Any chance I can make you show me how to do it?

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: Nice. One last question: If I add a caption beneath the drawing inside a `figure` environment, the caption is rotated just as (the beginning of) the house on the drawing. How do I avoid that? (I tried putting `\SpecialCoor` inside the `pspicture*` but wihtout effect.)

Comment: see edit. We have to save the current graphic state and restore it at the end of the `pspicture` environment

Comment: Perfect, Herbert!

Comment: Arrrh! I actually have a one other problem (sorry): How do I draw the house in 3D instead of just drawing the end of it in the `(x,z)` plane? I tried to add for example `\psline(3,0,0)(3,7,0)` but that (of course) just adds a line from `(3,0)` to `(3,7)`.

Comment: Where is the problem?? That are _all_ simple lines. You must draw the coordinate axes with labels then it is easy to see what coordinates do you have to choose. See my edited answer for the 2d solution.

Comment: I have no idea what I missed; what you do it obvious and simple. Thank you!

Comment: After a closer examination, I have found that the triangles making up the isometric paper are not regular; the vertival side is shorter than the two others. How do I make them regular?

Comment: I already told you that everything is done by the setting of the transmations matrix: 0.5 is sin(30)

Comment: Okay; I didn't realize that `[1 0.5 0 1 0 -400]` was the transformation matrix. If I change the first `1` to `0.8660254` (almost sqrt(3)/2), it works. Thank you.