# Isometric grid with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

A very simple square grid can be made with tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering
\tikz\draw [thin] (0,0) grid (20,26)
\end{document}
```

How can one make an **isometric grid** with tikz? I found [one with PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114278/isometric-paper-and-drawing-on-it-with-pstricks), but it is not easy to customize. And I'd like a solution that does not require PSTricks, if at all possible.

Comment: The answer has been updated for better use of nodes' anchors as reference points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example with `kite` shapes. Command `\isogrid{rows}{cols}` draws an isometri grid with `rows+1` rows and `cols+1`.

Using `nodes` instead of pure lines, nodes anchors can help to draw over the grid.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\tikzset{
    iso/.style={kite, draw, kite vertex angles=120,  minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt}
}

\newcommand{\isogrid}[2]{
\foreach \i [count=\row from 0, remember=\row as \lastrow (initially 0)] in {0,...,#1}{
    \foreach \j [count=\col from 0, remember=\col as \lastcol (initially 0)] in {0,...,#2}{
        \ifnum\row=0
            \ifnum\col=0
                \node[iso] (\row-\col) {\row-\col};
            \else
                \node[iso, anchor=left vertex] (\row-\col) at (\row-\lastcol.right vertex) {\row-\col};
            \fi
        \else
            \ifnum\col=0
                \node[iso, anchor=upper vertex] (\row-\col) at (\lastrow-\col.lower vertex) {\row-\col};
            \else
                \node[iso, anchor=left vertex] (\row-\col) at (\row-\lastcol.right vertex) {\row-\col};
            \fi
        \fi
        }
    }
\draw (0-0.left vertex)--(#1-0.left vertex);
\foreach \i in {0,...,#2}{
    \draw (0-\i.upper vertex)--(#1-\i.lower vertex);
    \draw (0-\i.right vertex)--(#1-\i.right vertex);
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\isogrid{19}{9}
\begin{scope}[line width=2pt]
\draw (1-3.right vertex)--(3-5.right vertex)--(7-1.right vertex)--(5-0.left vertex)--cycle;
\draw (5-0.left vertex)--(13-0.left vertex)--(15-1.right vertex)--(7-1.right vertex);
\draw (3-5.right vertex)--(5-5.right vertex)--(7-7.right vertex)--(10-7.right vertex)--(11-8.right vertex)--(12-7.right vertex)--(13-8.right vertex)--(15-7.upper vertex)--(13-5.upper vertex)--(10-5.upper vertex)--(8-3.upper vertex)--(5-5.right vertex);
\draw (9-5.lower vertex)--(7-7.right vertex);
\draw (12-5.lower vertex)--(10-7.right vertex);
\draw (11-8.right vertex)--(16-8.right vertex)--(17-7.lower vertex)--(13-3.lower vertex)--(15-1.right vertex);
\draw (7-3.lower vertex)--(13-3.lower vertex);
\draw (14-7.lower vertex)--(17-7.lower vertex);

\draw[dashed] (13-0.left vertex)--(9-3.right vertex)--(1-3.right vertex);
\draw[dashed] (9-3.right vertex)--(14-8.right vertex)--(15-7.right vertex)--(16-8.right vertex);
\draw[dashed] (12-7.right vertex)--(15-7.right vertex);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]