# PSTricks Drawing: LuaLaTeX Gives Unexpected Output

Tags: luatex, pstricks, luapstricks

**Code**

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114278/isometric-paper-and-drawing-on-it-with-pstricks
\centering
 \psset{
   linejoin = 2
 }
 \SpecialCoor
  \begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-2)(10,8.5)
    \pstVerb{gsave [\fpeval{sqrt(3)/2} 0.5 0 1 0 -400] concat}
   {\psset{
      linewidth = 0.3pt,
      linecolor = black!50
    }
     \multido
       {\i = 0+1}
       {25}
       {\psline(\i,-4)(\i,20)
        \psline(!-5 \i\space 10 sub)(!20 \i\space 10 sub)
        \rput(!0 \i\space 15 sub){\psline(0,0)(!\i\space abs dup add dup)}}
   }
   {\psset{
      linewidth = 2pt
    }
    \pspolygon(8,2)(8,6)(11,9)(11,5)
    \pspolygon(1,2)(1,6)(8,6)(8,2)
    \pspolygon(1,6)(2.5,9.5)(9.5,9.5)(8,6)
    \psline(11,9)(9.5,9.5)
   {\psset{
      linestyle = dashed
    }
    \pspolygon(4,5)(4,9)(11,9)(11,5)
    \pspolygon(1,6)(4,9)(4,5)(1,2)
    \psline(4,9)(2.5,9.5)
    \pstVerb{grestore}
   }
   }
  \end{pspicture*}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

When I compile using `lualatex` I get the following wrong output:

[image: wrong]

However, when I compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` I get the following correct output:

[image: correct]

**Question**

How can I compile using `lualatex` and get the correct output?

Comment: Did you get this error in your log?  Extended graphic state modifications dropped since `pdfmanagement-testphase` is not loaded.

Comment: @Thruston Yes, I did. I've added the log file. (If I add `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}` before `\documentclass`, I get the following warnings and error: `Package pdfmanagement Warning: The PDF resources management is not active
(pdfmanagement)                command '\pdfmanagement_add:nnn ' ignored.


Package pdfmanagement Warning: The PDF resources management is not active
(pdfmanagement)                command '\pdfmanagement_add:nnn ' ignored.

! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \__pdf_backend_metadata_stream:n

l.49 \end{document}`.)

Comment: @Thruston: That is a simple message and not an error!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg:  You also need the line `\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}`. However, it is not important for your problem!  PostScript and luapstricks have different coordinate systems for y. We'll investigate ...

Comment: @user187802 in a current LaTeX you should use `\DocumentMetadata{}`. And loading the pdfmanagement-testphase package first is no longer needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer:  Sure, but Svend uses already the `\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}`

Comment: @user187802 even then \DocumentMetadata{} is the right command in a current LaTeX. The other command is deprecated and will disappear at some time, so should only be mentioned if people explictly mention that they use an older tex systems.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg you are flooding the home page with edits

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry. It was just to edit the words in the header to make them start with capital letter. I'll stop immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until we find a better (automatic) solution use it this way:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid](-2,-4)(10,12)
\ifPSTlualatex
  \pstVerb{ gsave [60 sin -0.5 0 1 0 100] concat }%
\else
  \pstVerb{ gsave [60 sin 0.5 0 1 0 -400] concat }%
\fi
{\psset{linewidth = 0.3pt,linecolor = black!50}%
    \multido{\i = 0+1}{25}{%
        \psline(\i,-4)(\i,20)
        \psline(!-5 \i\space 10 sub)(!20 \i\space 10 sub)
        \rput(!0 \i\space 15 sub){\psline(0,0)(!\i\space abs dup add dup)}}
}%
\psset{linewidth = 2pt}
\pspolygon(8,2)(8,6)(11,9)(11,5)
\pspolygon(1,2)(1,6)(8,6)(8,2)
\pspolygon(1,6)(2.5,9.5)(9.5,9.5)(8,6)
\psline(11,9)(9.5,9.5)
\psset{linestyle = dashed}
\pspolygon(4,5)(4,9)(11,9)(11,5)
\pspolygon(1,6)(4,9)(4,5)(1,2)
\psline(4,9)(2.5,9.5)
\psdot[dotscale=3](5,5)
\pspolygon[linecolor=red](1,1)(10,10)(10,0)(0,10)(0,0)
\pstVerb{grestore}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what's happened there?  You need a different current transformation matrix?

Comment: Yes, TeX has its origin in the upper left and PS in the lower left. The values are changed in the driver or in `luapstricks`. But in this case it is missing and must be added.

Comment: @user187802 Have you come up with an 'automatic' solution?

Comment: no, not that easy ...

Comment: @user187802 Any news regarding the issue?

Comment: No, forgot about it in the meantime ... :-). Will put it on the to-do-list again ...